# $P \implies \sim R$ entail $P \implies \sim ( R $ or $ S)$?

Tags: logic

Does $P \implies \sim R$ entail $P \implies \sim ( R $ or $ S)$?

Can anyone please help me  ?  Is the other way correct  ?

Can I prove or disprove it using Truth Table ?

Comment: What does $\sim R$ mean?

Comment: @Mathphysmeister $\sim$ is another symbol for $\neg$, the negation.

Comment: Suppose $P \implies \sim R$ is true, then either $P,\sim R$ both true or $P$ false. So if $P$ is false then clearly $P \implies \sim (R \ \mathrm{or} S)$. Now suppose that $P,\sim R$ are both true. Then $R$ is false. $S$ can be true or false. Suppose $S$ is true, then $\sim(R \ \mathrm{or} S)$ is false. And if $S$ is false then $\sim (R \ \mathrm{or} S)$ is true. Thus we conclude that it cannot be correct. It depends on how rigorous your course is whether you can use this type of truth table reasoning or whether you really need to use deduction rules!

Comment: I think the simplest way is to use the definition of $\implies$: $P\implies Q$ is $(\sim P)\vee Q$.

Comment: Yes, you can disprove it with Truth Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P \implies \sim(R \lor S)$ can be written as $P \implies \sim R \land \sim S$.

This is De Morgan's law at work and can be shown using truth tables. Alternatively, we can reason intuitively: $\sim(R \lor S)$ means neither $R$ nor $S$ is true, or, in other words, both $R$ *and* $S$ must be false.

From $P \implies \sim R$, if $P$ is true we know only $\sim R$. For all we know about $S$, $S$ could be true which would render $\sim R \land \sim S$ false. Thus, $P \implies \sim(R \lor S)$ is not a logical consequence of $P \implies \sim R$.

A more concise answer:

For atomic or compound propositions $A$ to entail $B$, $B$ must be true under every *truth assignment* such that $A$ is true.  A truth assignment is a vector-valued function from the space of *n* atomic propositions to the *n*-Cartesian product of the set $\{0, 1\}$.

Let us examine the truth assignment $v(P, R, S) = (1, 0, 1)$. Under this truth assignment, $A$ sure is true, but $B$ is false *because $P$ is true but $\sim R \land \sim S$* is false. So we have found a truth assignment under which $A$ is true but $B$ is false, implying that $A$ does not entail $B$.